# How to get full path of last modified file in directory including nested directories?

Tags: bash, shell

How would I modify this code to give me the full file path of the last modified file in the code directory, including nested sub-directories?

```
# Gets the last modified file in the code directory.
get_filename(){
    cd "$code_directory" || no_code_directory_error # Stop script if directory doesn't exist.
    last_modified=$(ls -t | head -n1)
    echo "$last_modified"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use `find` instead of `ls`, because the use of `ls` is an [anti-pattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
2. Use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to prefix your data with a sort key.
3. Sort the data.
4. Take what you need.
5. Remove the sort key.
6. Post process the data.

```sh
find "$code_directory" -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |
  sort -rn |
  head -1 |
  sed 's/^[0-9.]\+ //' |
  xargs readlink -f
```

Comment: The only improvement to this is to guard against the case of a filename that contains a newline: find use `\0` instead of `\n`; sort, head, sed `-z`; xargs `-0`

Comment: Those fixes generally require GNU userland utilities though, so they will work on Linux but not on many other platforms.

Comment: @tripleee Your fight against GNU tools is also a fight against progress. And this is not useless progress like systemd. It is good to be able to work with zero terminated data.

Comment: I have nothing against the GNU tools, I love them; but answers which depend on them should point this out, so that people who do not have the GNU tools don't have to find out the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

**ls -t** sort by modification time and if you want first one you can add **| head -1**, R helps you recursively sort files, I think the only tips here is ls -tR doesn't stack all files then sort them, so you can use

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %f\n" | sort -rn > out.txt
```

Comment: Bare in mind in the results that `%T@` yields the number of elapsed seconds since epoch. (for Linux systems, see [the manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`realpath`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) utility.

```
# Gets the last modified file in the code directory.
get_filename(){
    cd "$code_directory" || no_code_directory_error # Stop script if directory doesn't exist.
    last_modified=$(ls -t | head -1)
    echo "$last_modified"
    realpath "$last_modified"
}
```

Output:

```
blah.txt
/full/path/to/blah.txt
```